# Can I run two bash commands at once and send only one to the background?

Tags: bash, background, ampersand

In the interest of avoiding an XY problem, I'm trying to set up an iTerm profile to do the following when I hit the hotkey.

1. cd to ~/my/directory/
2. start an http server in the background
3. **let me stay in ~/my/directory/**

The command I'm working with so far is `cd ~/my/directory/ && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &> /dev/null &`

This works great for starting the server on the project root. The problem is, after it starts running in the background, my pwd is NOT ~/my/directory/. I guess that part is sent to the background too.

Is there a way to accomplish step 3 without having to cd again manually afterward?

Comment: try `;` instead of `&&` or put second command in `( )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

`;` instead of `&&`

```
cd ~/my/directory/ ; python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &> /dev/null &
```

or second command in `( )`

```
cd ~/my/directory/ && (python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &> /dev/null &)
```

Comment: Perfect! [gently kicks self for not trying parens]... Thanks for the help!